# How to link to direct2d methods with rust ffi?

Tags: winapi, rust, methods, direct2d

So I tried to follow the [win32 guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/module-3---windows-graphics) from rust with my own bindings.

I have no problem using the functions like CreateWindowExW and RegisterClassEx. There are no problems with my custom types and function signatures.

I have a problem with DIrect2D's methods.

I can use functions like [D2D1CreateFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-d2d1createfactory), like this:

```rs
#[link(name = "d2d1")]
extern "system" {
    pub fn D2D1CreateFactory(factoryType: D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE, riid: REFIID, pFactoryOptions: *const D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS, ppIFactory: *mut *mut VOID) -> HRESULT;
}
```

But when I try to use the methods like [ID2D1Factory::CreateHwndRenderTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/id2d1factory-createhwndrendertarget) and [ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateSolidColorBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-createsolidcolorbrush(constd2d1_color_f__id2d1solidcolorbrush)):

```rs
#[link(name = "d2d1")]
extern "system" {
    pub fn CreateHwndRenderTarget(renderTargetProperties: *const D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES, hwndRenderTargetProperties: *const D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES, hwndRenderTarget: *mut ID2D1HwndRenderTarget) -> HRESULT;
    pub fn CreateSolidColorBrush(color: *const D2D1_COLOR_F, solidColorBrush: *mut ID2D1SolidColorBrush) -> HRESULT;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
rust.c1xdqhqliin6vee.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateHwndRenderTarget referenced in function _ZN4rust23CreateGraphicsResources17hfd7581378c7f6240E
          rust.c1xdqhqliin6vee.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateSolidColorBrush referenced in function _ZN4rust23CreateGraphicsResources17hfd7581378c7f6240E
          C:\Users\x\Desktop\rust\target\debug\deps\rust.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I know somehow [windows-rs](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs) and [winapi-rs](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs) solves it. But windows-rs's code is too complicated for me to undestand it, and winapi-rs's macros are a nightmare.

Is there a simple way to link to these methods, or do I need to set up a system with structs and traits like the two libraries above?

But even if I do set up a system like those, I still do not understand how would that be different  from what I am doing. Methods in the end are just functions right? And these Direct2d methods are not even like traditional methods. From what I have seen, the interface(ID2D1Factory) is just used as a namespace to group up these functions. There are no shared variables and state between them.

How can I solve this and use the methods? What are the two libraries doing differently than me?

Comment: Pretty sure `d2d1.dll` is a COM DLL, which means no, *methods are not just functions* (well they are, but you can't just link to them by name). I have no idea how you link against a COM interface from Rust.

Comment: That's not how COM works. The function names of interfaces do not exist in code. They are provided as a convenience for humans so that they don't have to fiddle with indices into function pointer tables. Consequently, you cannot ask the linker to look them up (that's what the error is telling you). You'd have to either build the interface vtables yourself, or use a crate that does it for you (like winapi or windows). The latter has a [Direct2D sample](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/tree/master/crates/samples/direct2d) you can use as a reference.

Comment: Ok, but how? I can copy the original struct from windows api, and can create a system with traits and structs in rust. But how would the compiler know that my structs and traits are vtables? And to make vtables I need the original methods address in the dll or in memory or whatever no? There is no way I can find out that. Can someone recommend a resource or article where I can find out more about this? I really dont get it.